# Using ms-resource in .xaml at windows 8 app

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-rt

How can I use ms-resource in page XAML file?

```
<Button  Name="btn_SaveNote" Content="ms-resource:Done" ></Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Strings from resource files in your windows 8 app.

Then use this

```
<Button x:Uid="StringName" Content="">
```

and in resource file it should be defined as

```
StringName.Content
```